# How can we import index.js by default ,and reducer which is not inside index.js file

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have no class named or function reducers in my code but explanation says it takes index.js by default in index.js there is class or function  named reducer  i am having no errors and compiling fine how?

I have used create-react -app to create app

The following is index.js code which is reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import movies from './movies_reducer';

const rootReducer =  combineReducers({
    movies
})

export default rootReducer
```

The following is the index.js file where i am using index.js from reducer

```
import reducers from './reducers'

const   createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore)

ReactDOM.render(

<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware()}>
<App />
</Provider>,
```

How the above code works please explain

Comment: refer to this link if u want to understand it : https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-structure-a-react-app-or-why-theres-no-such-thing-3ede534ef1ed

Answer (score 1):

Importing a directory is syntactical sugar for importing the index.js file inside the directory. Provided you have a directory named reducers and a file named index.js inside it, the following imports are equivalent.

```
import reducers from './reducers'
import reducers from './reducers/index'
import reducers from './reducers/index.js'
```

In addition, default exports can be imported with any name.

```
export default rootReducer

// file.js - the following import statements import the same rootReducer
import reducers from './reducers'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import anyName from './reducers'
```

Comment: Thanks 

But can you plese help whether reducers and rootReducer  are same i am thinking we are importing rootReducer

Comment: I don't understand you.

Comment: what reducers will have ? the file or the function which is inside the index.js (that is root reducers)  if it is having root reducers how  we are getting  rootreducers

Comment: Since it's a default export, it can be imported with any name but it is still the rootreducer that you exported.